# Is the following problem convex , quasiconvex, or nonconvex?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I want to get the optimal matrix $W$. But I am not sure whether it can be resolved.
Note that $W,\mu,\lambda_{1},\ldots,\lambda_{K} $ are variables, others are fixed.
Is it convex or quasiconvex or nonconvex? How can I solve it?

$F \in \mathbb{C}^{M \times K }$ is matrix .$\| \  \|_{F}$ is Frobenius norm. $U \in \mathbb{C}^{M \times (M-K) }$. $\hat{g}_{k} \in \mathbb{C}^{M}$.

The problem is here[image]

Comment: Can you please tell me what ${F}$ matrix is and also what is the $\mid\mid \cdot \mid\mid _F$ norm?

Comment: $F \in \mathbb{C}^{M \times K }$ is matrix .$\| \  \|_{F}$ is Frobenius norm. $U \in \mathbb{C}^{M \times (M-K) }$

Comment: When you write $$\mid\mid WF, W\mid\mid$$ do you mean matrix augmentation? I mean putting the two matrices side by side?

Comment: yes, you are right. Because $ \| WF\|_F^2 + \| W\|_F^2 = \| [WF, W]\|_F^2$

Comment: What do you mean by $[]\succeq$? Do you mean that big matrix is positive semidefinite? Or something else?

Comment: yes, positive semidefinite